# Filepicker.io Objective-c Absurd Data?

Tags: ios, nsdata, filepicker.io

I am making an iOS app that uses filepicker.io's iOS SDK  and I keep running into this issue when adding large videos. I crashes the entire app almost Immediately. Here is the issue:

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=532119552) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
2012-12-07 23:46:56.886 App_Name[1106:1d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception       'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteData initWithBytes:length:copy:freeWhenDone:bytesAreVM:]: absurd length: 4294967295, maximum size: 2147483648 bytes'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3ac1e2a3 0x34b0d97f 0x3ac1e1c5 0x35980407 0x359877bf 0x3598777d 0x5d41d 0x6064d 0x5ffc3 0x38f1111f 0x38f14b97 0x38f17139 0x38f1591d 0x38f15ac1 0x35c7aa11 0x35c7a8a4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

This is very peculiar and all I found about this is that it has to do with memory management. How can I fix this????

Comment: That video isn't actually half a gigabyte...is it?

Comment: oh no, it is only 3 min.

Comment: If you will notice, 4294967295 is the highest for a 32-bit integer

Comment: Hi there. iOS dev at filepicker. Email me at liyan@filepicker.io and let's figure this one out together. Give the 32bit connection, there's  probably a int where there should be a long. There may also be memory issues as we try to upload large uncompressed video so we can take a look at that too.